# Oracle query with order by perfomance issue

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, sql-order-by, rownum

I have really complicated query:

```
select * from (
select * from tbl_user ...
where ...
and date_created between :date_from and :today
...
order by date_created desc
) where rownum <=50;
```

Currently query is fast enough because of where clause (only 3 month before today, date_from = today - 90 days).

I have to remove this clause, but it causes performance degradation.
What if first calculate date_from by `

```
SELECT MIN(date_created) where...
```

and then insert this value into main query? Set of data will be the same. Will it improve performance? Does it make sense?
Could anyone have any assumption about optimization?

Comment: Will, currently your question is very difficult to understand. Please edit your post to better state your issue and include your schema and full queries. We can't fully help you optimize your solution if you don't provide such things.

Comment: Which columns are indexed, and how many rows are we dealing with here? Also have you checked the Explain plan and/or Autotrace for information on the execution plan?

Comment: The limiting clause (finding only the most recent 50 rows) is very helpful - even if you include all the data, not just the last three months, you wouldn't see a big degradation in performance. This is because the optimizer sees the outer query `where` clause and it does not order ALL the rows in the inner query - it only looks for the highest 50 values of `date_created`. Do you have an index on `date_created`? That should help a lot.

Comment: Comment on date_created subset:  look at the execution plan, because the SQL as written would require implicit type conversion; if oracle does this on the column, then even if it has an index, it won't be used.  To get around implicit type conversion, then explicitly use to_date function around the input strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an `order by` operation will of course cause the query to take a little longer to return.  That being said, it is almost always faster to sort in the DB than it is to sort in your application logic.

It's hard to really optimize without the full query and schema information, but I'll take a stab at what seems like the most obvious to me.

**Converting to Rank()**

Your query could be a lot more efficient if you use a windowed `rank()` function. I've also converted it to use a [common table expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL) (aka CTE). This doesn't improve performance, but does make it easier to read.

```
with cte as (
  select 
    * 
    , rank() over (
      partition by
        -- insert what fields differentiate your rows here
        -- unlike a group by clause, this doesn't need to be
        -- every field
      order by
        date_created desc
    )
  from 
    tbl_user 
    ...
  where 
    ...
    and date_created between :date_from and :today
)
select 
  * 
from 
  cte
where
  rk <= 50
```

**Indexing**

1. If `date_created` is not indexed, it probably should be.
2. Take a look at your autotrace results. Figure out what filters have the highest cost. These are probably unindexed, and maybe should be.

If you post your schema, I'd be happy to make better suggestions.

Comment: Why will `rank()` make the query faster? I don't believe that - do you have any documentation for that, or a theoretical argument? The `ORDER BY` clause in `rank()` does the same work as the separate `ORDER BY` clause in the OP's original query. And in both cases, whether using separate `order by` clause or `rank()`, the limiting `where` clause (`rownum <= 50` or `rnk <= 50`) will allow the optimizer to rewrite so that only the "first" 50 rows are identified, instead of ordering the entire set.

Comment: Besides, if ties are possible, the correct function to use is `row_number()` rather than `rank()`.

Comment: Comment on date_created subset: look at the execution plan, because the SQL as written would require implicit type conversion; if oracle does this on the column, then even if it has an index, it won't be used. To get around implicit type conversion, then explicitly use to_date function around the input strings.

Comment: @RogerCornejo No. Assuming a date is passed to the bind parameter it's fine.

Comment: @Jacobm001 I'm not saying the optimizer will use implicit type conversion, rather I suggest to check (rather than assume) on it.  The details coming from the execution plan (or SQL tuning advisor) should tell you what predicates are used for access (i.e. index being used) or filter (just data subsetting).